# Generating Cyclic Words in Python

Tags: python, loops, logic, sequence, cyclic

I have an array like

```
myarray = 'ABCDE'
```

and I want output as

```
required_output = [AB,BC,CD,DE,EA]  ## A cyclic form of array 'ABCDE'
```

I used following code

```
for i in range(len(myarray) + 1):

    a = i % len(myarray) ; b = i % len(myarray) + 2

    print myarray[a : b]
```

result I get as

```
AB , BC, CD, DE, E , AB
```

what logic I am missing which is causing 'e' to appear instead of 'ea' and also 'ab' should not have appeared ???

Another way I found was to use a loop like this

```
for i in range(1,len(myarray)):

    print myarray[i-1] + myarray[i]
```

gives output as

```
'EA','AB','BC','CD','DE'  ## where the last element 'EA' comes in the begining
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not too hard to see what's going wrong

```
>>> myarray = 'ABCDE'
>>> for i in range(len(myarray) + 1):
...     a = i % len(myarray) ; b = i % len(myarray) + 2
...     print a, b, myarray[a: b]
... 
0 2 AB
1 3 BC
2 4 CD
3 5 DE
4 6 E
0 2 AB
```

There's no way you're going to get a slice like 'EA' without doing something heroic like

```
>>> myarray[::-4]
'EA'
```

The `+ 1` is obviously going to give you one more output than the number of items in myarray

Easy fix is something like this

```
>>> for i in range(len(myarray)):
...     print (myarray*2)[i:i+2]
... 
AB
BC
CD
DE
EA
```

Comment: The second answer was really pythonic..Previous answers seldom consider what if i wanted to create strings of 3 or 4 or n instead of just 2. In this answer if i change i + 2 t0 i + n i can make such cyclic strings of any size. 

One more question... can you explain me the syntax (myarray*2)[i:i+2]... why (myarray*2)??? I checked the output and found that it solves the single last element 'E' problem.... please explain the logic behind that.. thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` here:

```
def cycle(s):
    return [ ''.join(x) for x in zip(s, s[1:]+s[:1])]

>>> cycle('ABCDE')
['AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'DE', 'EA']
>>> cycle('ABCD')
['AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'DA']
```

Using indexes, similar to your method:

```
def cycle(s):
    for i in range(len(s)):
        yield s[i] + s[(i+1)%len(s)]

print list(cycle('ABCDE'))
print list(cycle('ABCD'))
```

**Output:**

```
['AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'DE', 'EA']
['AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'DA']
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
print [data[i: (i + 2)] for i in range(len(data) - 1)] + [data[-1] + data[0]]
```

**Output**

```
['AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'DE', 'EA']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[''.join(a) for a in zip(myarray,myarray[1:]+myarray[0])]
```

output:

```
['AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'DE', 'EA']
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps you:

```
In [1]: m = 'ABCDE'

In [2]: ml = list(m)

In [3]: zip(ml, ml[1:] + [m[0]])
Out[3]: [('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'D'), ('D', 'E'), ('E', 'A')]
```